# Hibernate one to many mapping DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hibernate One to many relation Below Process will work

1. insert into parent table
2. insert into child table
3. update the parent primary key in child table

Suppose if i am having a foreign key constrain in database for parent and child table
my step 2 will fail as with DataIntegrityViolationException.

What is the best solution

## Heading

Comment: Do you mean update on your foreign key  in the child table. I don't see how update on a primary key is possible. That effectivly would be new insert.

Comment: post your existing mapping. The way it is stated the question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

You should go with hibernate inheritance feature to achieve this